# Form submit from Bootstrap 3 and JSP get parameter

Tags: forms, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3, getparameter

I'm new to Bootstrap. But I'm pretty familiar with HTML. The thing is I cannot get parameter values from JSP. The parameters are from HTML page with Bootstrap 3. Here're the code. I don't understand. If I make simple html only page, then I could get the parameters.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="makeResv.jsp">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">           
            <div class="control-group col-md-5">
                <label for="checkIn">date1</label>
                <div id="date-container">
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <input type="text" id="checkIn" class="form-control"><span
                            class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group col-md-5">
                <label for="checkOut">date2</label>
                <div id="date-container">
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <input type="text" id="checkOut" class="form-control"><span
                            class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In a JSP page, I'm just doing the following.

```
String checkIn = request.getParameter("checkIn");
String checkOut = request.getParameter("checkOut");
out.println(checkIn + " " + checkOut);
```

What's wrong with the above HTML code with Bootstrap?? Please give me some advise. Thanks!!

BTW, I'm using datepicker JavaScript library, but I don't think that affect the results. I cannot add the library code here but it works great anyway.
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bootstrap is same as HTML. The problem you are having is because you do not have any `name` attribute defined in your `input` element. You define `id` but to access submited variables via POST (`request.getParameter()` function) you need to have `name` attribute defined:

Replace `<input>` lines like this:

```
<input type="text" name="checkIn" id="checkIn" class="form-control">
```

And

```
<input type="text" name="checkOut" id="checkOut" class="form-control"><
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't noticed it and just focused on Bootstrap grammar.

Comment: Thanks this was very little thing which actually get skipped from mind, specifying name along with Id worked =)